# Таймер в Python: выйти из программы если пользователь не предоставил ввод за указанное время

Tags: python, время, таймер

Как сделать таймер в терминале, который будет считать время работы программы, и через 5 минут после бездействия пользователя выиходить из программы? Мне удалось сделать таймер который считает время, но как только появляется в программе input , то функция пересает работать, так как инпут начинает свою работу. Вот код котрый имелся, видимо такое решение не подходит.

```
import sys, time, os

def start_controller(user):

   start = time.time()
   PERIOD_OF_TIME = 300
   os.system('clear')
   print_menu()
   choice = get_choice()
   while choice != "0":
       os.system('clear')
       if choice == "1":
           start += PERIOD_OF_TIME
           print_student_list(Student.student_list, 
 AllAttendance.all_attendance_list)

       if time.time() > start + PERIOD_OF_TIME:
           os.system("clear")
           print('logout')
           Database.save_all_data_to_csv()
           sys.exit()
```

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы  [input() прервался спустя какое-то время](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15533404/4279)?

Comment: да, именно,  чтобы можно было вытйи из программы,

Answer (score 2):

Если вы не используете цикл событий, который предоставляет возможность выполнить/отменить действие спустя какое-то время ([примеры: tkinter, gtk, twisted, asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279)), то простой переносимый способ выйти из программы по таймеру, это использовать потоки и `os._exit`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from threading import Timer

timeout = 5
t = Timer(timeout, os._exit, [1])
t.start()
try:
    prompt = "У вас есть %d секунд чтобы ввести ответ...\n" % timeout
    answer = input(prompt)
finally:
    t.cancel()
```

Обратите внимание: [`os._exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit) аварийно завершает процесс, не вызывая функции, зарегистрирванные с [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#atexit), не очищая буферы потоков ввода/вывода итд.

Comment: Отличный вариант, подскажите как в течении программы после какого-то действия добавить время к такймеру? Чтобы выходило позже.

Comment: @ValekPotapov "добавить" время можно отменив (`t.cancel()`) предыдущий Timer и запустив новый с желаемым временем. Если часто это делать приходится, то чтобы избежать создание новых потоков для каждого Timer, [можно WatchdogTimer использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115590/4279), который реализует reset() метод, который отодвигает срабатывание таймера на .timeout секунд.

Comment: Практически получилось решить задачу, благодарю!