# Как сделать таймер в Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, таймер

Как сделать таймер в Питоне для подсчета времени? То есть таймер, который будет проверять сколько прошло секунд с указанного момента и если пройдет 5 больше секунд программа должна завершать свою работу.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как правильно сделать временный цикл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577284/23044)

Comment: что вы хотите, чтобы в течении 5 секунд происходило перед выходом из программы?

Comment: ожидание ввода (input)

Comment: возможный дубликат: [Таймер в Python: выйти из программы если пользователь не предоставил ввод за указанное время](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694130/23044)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно сделать временный цикл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577284/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Таймер в Python: выйти из программы если пользователь не предоставил ввод за указанное время](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694130/%d0%a2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-python-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

Ну... если пройдёт 5 секунд... Здесь несколько вариантов. Опишите нужный вам. Я приведу два:

Если вам нужно просто ожидание в течение 5 секунд и выход из кода, то просто используйте библиотеку time:

```
import time
#ваш код
time.sleep(5) #"засыпание" выполнения кода на 5 секунд
#тут не пишите ничего и программа сама завершиться, ну или же используйте exit()
```

Вам нужно, чтобы в течение 5 секунд выполнялся код и потом он выходил, тогда нужно использовать потоки (модуль threading) и тот же модуль time:

```
import threading
import time

#создаём функцию для нашего потока, которая будет закрывать код через 5 секунд вне зависимости от обстоятельств
def timer():
    time.sleep(5)
    exit()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=time, name="thread1_name") #создаём поток thread1 и указываем ему на уже созданную функцию timer
thread1.start() # начинаем поток
#тут ваш код
```

Итог: выполняется ваш код и через пять секунд, после его начала, код закрывается (если же вы раньше пяти секунд не использовали exit() )